# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

when i am running my app.js file i am getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string.

the whole error in my terminal is:

$ node app.js
(node:18676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
at parseConnectionString (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:565:21)
at connect (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:282:3)
at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:224:5
at maybePromise (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:665:3)
at MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:220:10)
at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:820:12
at new Promise ()
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:817:19)
at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:345:10
at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
at new Promise ()
at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1135:10)
at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:344:20)
at Object. (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\app.js:3:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1076:30)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:18676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not
handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:18676) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:18676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Extra\fruit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:184:20)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:18676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not
handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)

The Code is given below:

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('monogodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB',{ useNewUrlParser:true,family:4});

const fruitSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
name:String,
rating:Number,
review:String
});

const Fruit=mongoose.model("Fruit",fruitSchema);

const fruit=new Fruit({
name:"Apple",
rating:7,
review:"Pretty Good!"
});

fruit.save();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo at the beginning of your connection string, `monogodb` instead of `mongodb`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Solution make sure your MongoDB URL connection string is correct or misspelled
   "mongodb://myDBReader:D1fficultP%40ssw0rd@mongodb0.example.com:27017/?authSource=admin" or
   "mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017"